# Type '{ uri: string | null | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ImageSourcePropType | undefined'

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and getting the error described the title on the `react-native-elements` component.

Here is my component:

```js
export type Props = {
  navigation: any;
  chats: Array<string>;
};

export interface ChatProps {
  id: string;
  chatName: string;
}

export interface AvatarSource {
  uri?: string | undefined;
}

const HomeScreen: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation }) => {
  const signOutUser = () => {
    auth.signOut().then(() => {
      navigation.replace("Login");
    });
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <View style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={signOutUser} activeOpacity={0.5}>
            <Avatar
              rounded
              source={{
                uri: auth?.currentUser?.photoURL,
              }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ),
      headerRight: () => (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <AntDesign name="camerao" size={24} color="black" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("AddChat")}
            activeOpacity={0.5}
          >
            <SimpleLineIcons name="pencil" size={24} color="black" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ),
    });
  }, []);

  const enterChat = ({ id, chatName }: ChatProps) => {
    navigation.navigate("Chat", {
      id,
      chatName,
    });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        {chats.map(({ id, data: { chatName } }) => {
          return (
            <CustomListItem
              key={id}
              id={id}
              chatName={chatName}
              enterChat={enterChat}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

The typescript error is on:

`source={{ uri:auth?.currentUser?.photoURL}}`

I am still unsure on how to define the type here, I have tried above as you can see but don't know what is the next step for it to work.

Any idea on how to define this / correct it in Typescript?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Undeclared/unimported types/values should be fixed.  Ideally, unless you want to tag this with react or react-native-elements, you should remove dependencies on these third party packages.

Answer (score 0):

I not know if understand correctly your question, im needed more details.

But, I understand that you have typescript problem in `source` property in Avatar component, so maybe you can create a variable with concatenated value of uri, because the value of uri expected is of type string and add on Props type with the following:

```js
export type Props {
  navigation: any;
  chats: Array<string>;
  url: string;
}

const url = auth?.currentUser?.photoURL;
```

But I would need to understand what exactly this Avatar component is about. Assuming the Avatar component maybe use `ImageBackground` with `ImageSourcePropType`  type, like this:

```js
// Avatar Component Example
import { ImageBackground, ImageSourcePropType } from 'react-native';

export function Avatar({ ...rest }: ImageSourcePropType) {
  <ImageBackground {...rest}>
   { /** Some code here **/}
  </ImageBackground>
}
```

This is just an idea, hope it helps.

Comment: This might be better suited as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Typically answers to incomplete questions are incomplete themselves.